# Securing Restful services with OAUTH

Tags: rest, oauth

Am new to RestfulServices. I wrote a restful webservice (Jersey).
But am not able to implement security on those serives.
Please share me how to provide security with OAUTH (Tutorial URLs or steps to follow).

Thanks in advance......

Comment: http://developers.sun.com/identity/reference/techart/restwebservices.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oauth in RESTful services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763180/oauth-in-restful-services)